# What needs to be done to write interrupt handler on linux without actual hardware?

Tags: c, linux, driver, device

Is there any Hardware emulator which can generate hardware interrupt on Linux. I am looking to write device drivers that could process hardware interrupts, read or write into hardware memory, deferred work, top and bottom halves processing, etc. Basically, looking to learn complete device driver end to end. But what hurdle is - how to simulate hardware. Do I really need some hardware that could generate an interrupt. I went through book LDD3, but there they are using `skull` - a chunk of kernel space memory emulating as a hardware, but this cannot generate an interrupt, or it can? pls, throw some light.

Comment: You could write your own operating system and use qemu emulator.

Comment: You can simulate an interrupt by hooking up a callback from _any_ real interrupt. The usual is a timer interrupt. In fact, some devices don't have interrupts but the driver simulates them by doing what I just mentioned. Or, you could write a driver from scratch and load it into a [your] custom built linux kernel [in lieu of the existing/standard driver] that you boot in a virtual machine (e.g. `virtualbox`, `vmware`, etc). That way, you can experiment without actually hurting anything.

Comment: Pretty sure the VHOST drivers on the host generate simulated interrupts in the VIRTIO drivers in the guest.

Comment: why do you need an interrupt handler in your device if it doesn't generate any asynchronous event?

Answer (score 0):

The skull driver of LDD3 doesn't generate interrupts, because there's no actual hardware to generate them.

Device driver interrupts are a mechanism that allows the cpu to begin attending some other task because the action being performed will be handled by an asynchronous interrupt.

For example, a floppy disk drive interrupt's the cpu as each byte of a disk transfer is readin if no dma is in use.  If DMA is being used, the disk will transfer directly to ram the bytes of the transfer until a full block (or a set of them) is actually transferred.  Then some hardware interrupt will come in.

A serial interface interrupts your computer in a programmed basis.  When a single character arrives, when a specific character arrives (let's say a `\r` char).

LDDP shows you how linux device drivers work..... but as the book cannot assume you have any concrete device, it is not capable of selecting a proper hardware to serve as usable (strange, as normally every pc has a parallel port or a serial port)  I think LDDP3 has some driver using the parallel port, but you must continue reading the book before you start with interrupting hardware.

Asynchronous interrupts must be programmed into the device (the device must know that it has to generate an interrupt at the end of the transfer) so they have to be activated.  For the interrupt to be properly catched, an interrupt handler must be installed **before** the first interrupt happens, or you'll get in an state in which no interrupt comes ever, because it arrived and was lost.  And finally, interrupts have to be acknowledged.  Once you have stored the data comming from the device, they have to be reactivated, so another interrupt can happen again.  You need to learn that you have to protect your processes from accessing the data structures shared with an interrupt handler and how to do this.  And all of this is explained in the book.... but you must read it, and don't stop in the skull driver which is the first driver developed in the book.

By the way, the `kill(2)` and `sigaction(2)` system calls of user mode are a very close approach into the world of hardware interrupts, because they are asynchronous, you can block them to occur, before entering a critical zone, and you can simulate them by `kill(2)`ing your process externally from another program.  You will not see the difference, but instead of having a full system crash, you only get a hung process to kill.